# Automated page size grab

Tags: web, automation, size

For a stats study, I am trying to automate a process which will grab the size of the home page of a domain including css, JavaScript, images, etc. How would I do this? I am willing to use any platform/programming language/browser.

Comment: @zoke - is it some sort of site grabber like `wget` ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget

Comment: @ajreal, sort of but it needs to grab the css, images, etc so I know how much bandwith a user uses to visit the page (assuming no caching).

Comment: @ajreal, The best way to describe what I want is to automate the collection of data that is presented in the net panel of firebug.

Comment: @zoke - Firefox add-ons like `Web Developer` - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/ should fix your requirement

Comment: @ajreal - why did'nt you make that an official answer? Just askin'. It might have a good reason that I am not aware of.

Comment: @TheBlastOne - if need to be automated, other tools might better fit